# Bitcoin on old version of Bitcoin

Tags: bitcoin-core, client

I have Bitcoin on an old version on the Bitcoin app; more specifically Bitcoin.org version 0.3.22. I tried to transfer the Coins to a newer wallet, but they don't go through. has anyone had or worked around this issue before? Thank you!

Comment: Does 0.3.22 have getrawtransaction?

Comment: I would strongly advise you to make a backup of the wallet.dat file, and then upgrade to a recent version of Bitcoin Core instead. 0.3.22 is extremely outdated, and unlikely to be able to catch up with the network (or even construct transactions the network accepts).

Answer (score 0):

You can use pywallet to import the wallet.dat and export the private keys.

Then you can just sweep them into electrum or any other wallet supporting WIF.

Pywallet can be downloaded here: https://github.com/jackjack-jj/pywallet